# I want to replace `ls` with `ls -l` in eshell

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

I use `eshell-parse-command 'ls -l'` and I got this:

```
(progn (eshell-trap-errors
         (eshell-named-command "ls" (list "-l"))))
```

Then I write a alias in my .emacs file:

```
(defalias 'ls
  (progn ...))
```

But I doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following code to your configuration file.

```
(require 'em-alias)
(add-to-list 'eshell-command-aliases-list (list "ls" "ls -l"))
```

Comment: How to add multiple alias? Can I just add another list in this (add-to-list) expression? Or I have to add a new (add-to-list ...) each time I add something?

Comment: You can define aliases in file. Default alias file is ~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias(You can change alias file by variable eshell-aliases-file). Alias entry is like this 'alias ll ls -l $*'. See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Aliases.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I'm concerned on the elisp syntax to join multiple list here. In Clojure, I can `(conj '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))` Is it possible to do it in elisp?

Comment: I suppose you can use `append` like this. `(append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))`.

Comment: Thank you. I found an easy way: just use `alias` within eshell.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add alias to eshell is:

Open eshell,

```
alias alias-name definition
```

Eshell will automatically write it into `~/emacs.d/eshell/alias` (don't edit it yourself).

For example:

```
alias sau sudo aptitude update
```

Then you can type `sau` to launch sudo aptitude update.

Type `alias` (in eshll, of course) will list all the alias you've defined.

---

Some useful alias:

Map find-file to ff, then you can open a file in emacs with ff file:

```
alias ff 'find-file $1'
```

Map dired to d:

```
alias d 'dired $1'
```

---

Resources:
Mastering Eshell

```
http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell
```